# how to normalize rows of an opencv Mat without a loop?

Tags: c++, opencv, normalization

I did it in the following way

```
Mat temp, rp;    
for (int i = 0; i <= descriptors1.rows - 1; i++)
{
    normalize(descriptors1.row(i), temp);
    rp = normd1.rowRange(i, i+1);
    temp.copyTo(rp);
}
```

The descriptors1 above is a Mat.

But using a loop is time-consuming. Is there any nicer ways to do this?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with loops. They're not slow in C++ unlike what you might have heard about Matlab! If this is going to be used in an extremely time sensitive application then you can optimize the loop to remove the `i <= descriptors1.rows - 1` check in each iteration. Using `temp` is also unnecessary, you can pass `normd1.rowRange` to `normalize` directly to save time and do it in just one line.

**Edit:** You can use this method `normalize(A.row(i), _OutputArray(B.ptr(i), B.cols))`, or the template version of `_OutputArray`. In the way you've written the loop in each iteration  `descriptors1.rows - 1` should be evaluated as the compiler sees `rows` is not constant and most likely doesn't understand the functions in the loop do not change it. So I would change it to something like:

```
for (i = descriptors1.rows - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Though, you need to check the code generated by your compiler to make sure it's optimized, and also consider loop unrolling. Google can find you a lot of material on optimizing loops if this is really the bottleneck of your code.

Comment: 1, If the check `i <= descriptors1.row-1` is removed, then how to stop the loop after the last row has been processed? 2, The expression `normalize(A.row(i), B.row(i))` seems to be illegal.